# Loop through array to the Cartesian power n

Tags: c#, arrays, cartesian-product

I want to loop through the array which is the result of the array to the Cartesian power n. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#n-ary_product

This is what I want to achieve, just with n depth:

```
int[] array = new int[] { 5, -4, ... }
foreach(int a in array) {
    foreach(int b in array) {
        foreach(int c in array) {
           ...
           int[] NewArray = new int[] { a, b, c, ... }
```

In Python this is equivalent to:

```
from itertools import product
for (NewArray in product(array, repeat=n)):
    print(NewArray)
```

I do not know how I can implement this in C#.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can try recursive solution.

Comment: `Enumerable.Repeat(array, n).Aggregate((IEnumerable<int[]>)new[] {new int[0]}, (a, b) => a.SelectMany(c => b, (d, e) => { var f = new int[d.Length + 1]; d.CopyTo(f, 0); f[d.Length] = e; return f; }))`

Comment: [Computing a cartesian product with LINQ](https://ericlippert.com/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/).

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a cartesian product with a little math and `yield return`:

```
static public IEnumerable<T[]> Product<T>(IList<T> items, int repeat) {
    var total = (int)Math.Pow(items.Count, repeat);
    var res = new T[repeat];
    for (var i = 0 ; i != total ; i++) {
        var n = i;
        for (var j = repeat-1 ; j >= 0 ; j--) {
            res[j] = items[n % items.Count];
            n /= items.Count;
        }
        yield return res;
    }
}
```

Calling it like this

```
foreach (var arr in Product(new[] {"quick", "brown", "fox"}, 3)) {
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("-", arr));
}
```

produces the following output:

```
quick-quick-quick
quick-quick-brown
quick-quick-fox
quick-brown-quick
quick-brown-brown
quick-brown-fox
quick-fox-quick
quick-fox-brown
quick-fox-fox
brown-quick-quick
brown-quick-brown
brown-quick-fox
brown-brown-quick
brown-brown-brown
brown-brown-fox
brown-fox-quick
brown-fox-brown
brown-fox-fox
fox-quick-quick
fox-quick-brown
fox-quick-fox
fox-brown-quick
fox-brown-brown
fox-brown-fox
fox-fox-quick
fox-fox-brown
fox-fox-fox
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/FXBhVb)

Answer (score -1):

you can calculate cartesian product of two arrays like below

```
    string[][] CartesianProduct(string[] arr1, string[] arr2)
    {
        // for each s1 in arr1, extract arr2, 
        // then pass s1 and s2 into a newly-made string array.
        return arr1.SelectMany(s1 => arr2, (s1, s2) => new string[] { s1, s2 })
            .ToArray();
    }
```

Lets say you have two array namely

```
    string[] set1 = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };
    string[] set2 = new string[] { "x", "y", "z" };
```

make a call to CartesianProduct function which would return the resulting value like below.

```
   var cartesionProduct = CartesianProduct (set1,set2);
```

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question. It’s not about finding the Cartesian product of two arrays, it’s about finding the product of any number of arrays.